# No highlights from nested inner hit when term contains brackets

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a document with a nested field and I'm having some trouble getting highlighting to work. Why am I not getting highlighting when my term query contains pointy brackets (<>)?

We have two fields in a nested mapping containing similar data:

```
"value": {
  "type": "keyword",
  "normalizer": "lowercase"
},
"valueWithQualifier": {
  "type": "keyword",
  "normalizer": "lowercase"
}
```

The `lowercase` normalizer uses the filters `["asciifolding", "lowercase"]`

The `value` is generally an alphanumeric string but the `valueWithQualifier` takes the form `value<qualifier>`. When I execute a term query on the `value` field, it generally returns highlighting information. When I execute a term query on the `valueWithQualifier` field, I never get highlighting info.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "assoc",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "assoc.value": "123abc"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "highlight": {
          "fields": {
            "assoc.value*": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns an inner hit with a highlight:

```
"highlight": {
  "assoc.value": [
    "<em>123abc</em>"
  ]
}
```

However, this query returns the inner_hit but no highlighting:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "assoc",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "assoc.valueWithQualifier": "123abc<qual>"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "highlight": {
          "fields": {
            "assoc.value*": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this does return the highlighting (but I'd rather use a term query due to efficiency):

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "assoc",
      "query": {
        "prefix": {
          "assoc.valueWithQualifier": "123abc"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "highlight": {
          "fields": {
            "assoc.value*": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

"highlight": {
  "assoc.valueWithQualifier": [
    "<em>123abc<qual></em>"
  ]
}
```

And before someone asks, I have tried adding `"encoder": "html"` to the highlight.

Comment: Could be that your field is considered `text` and not `keyword`, hence analyzed. Either try `terms: {"assoc.valueWithQualifier": ["123abc", "qual"]}` (if the loose precision is OK with you) or use a `match` query. If this is the issue, you should find a way to re-map this field (and its data...) to a `keyword` type for precise, unanalyzed `term` queries.

Comment: I've confirmed that the field in the mapping is a keyword. It's explicitly defined.

Comment: Oops sorry, you did show the fields mappings at the beginning of your post. Far fetched, but maybe try `"assoc.value*": {"type": "plain"}`? Other than that, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no dice. One funny thing is, if the qualifier has camelcase, it seems to work up until the first capital letter. So I have one like this: `123abc<qualPrimary>` and the prefix query works for `123abc<` and `123abc<qual` but not `123abc<qualP` which is very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug that was fixed in ES 6.2 (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/27604).